# How to use copyfile when there are spaces in the directory name?

Tags: python, windows, file-copying

I am trying to perform a simple file copy task under Windows and I am having some problems.

My first attempt was to use

```
import shutils

source = 'C:\Documents and Settings\Some directory\My file.txt'
destination = 'C:\Documents and Settings\Some other directory\Copy.txt'

shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
```

`copyfile` can't find the source and/or can't create the destination.

My second guess was to use

```
shutil.copyfile('"' + source + '"', '"' + destination + '"')
```

But it's failing again.

Any hint?

---

**Edit**

The resulting code is

```
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"C:\Documents and Settings\Some directory\My file.txt"'
```

Comment: Doesn't seem obvious to me. Maybe you should prove it.

Comment: Taken into account. I removed that useless word.

Comment: Don't just remove the word, remove *all* your assumptions. There is no reason for it to be failing just because of a space.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think spaces are to blame. You have to escape backslashes in paths, like this:

```
source = 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Some directory\\My file.txt'
```

or, even better, use the `r` prefix:

```
source = r'C:\Documents and Settings\Some directory\My file.txt'
```

Comment: That may work. I'm not defining the path, though, I have a scrit that browses a folder and returns the file names. `source` is defined somewhere else. How can I `r source`?

Comment: Well, you should escape it where it's defined. If it's not in the code, then it probably doesn't need to be escaped. Do a `print repr(source)` to make sure. The backslashes should be escaped then.

Comment: `print repr(source)` returns double-backslash'd paths.

Answer (score 4):

Use forward slashes or a r'raw string'.

Answer (score 3):

Copyfile handles space'd filenames.

You are not escaping the \ in the file paths correctly.

```
import shutils

source = 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Some directory\\My file.txt'
destination = 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Some other directory\\Copy.txt'

shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
```

To illustrate, try running this:

```
print 'Incorrect: C:\Test\Derp.txt'
print 'Correct  : C:\\Test\\Derp.txt'
```

It seems there are other issues as well.  `Errno 22` indicates another problem.  I've seen this error in the following scenarios:

- Source file or target file is in use by another process.
- File path contains fancy Unicode characters.
- Other access problems.

Comment: While this is true and that backslashes *should* be escaped, none of them are valid and so result in a backslash followed by the character as normal and so should not cause an error in this case.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Correct.  But I suspect he is sanitizing/anonymizing the paths in the code examples, so it is still worth considering.