# How to use FileUtils cp using directory name with spaces in Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, directory, cp, fileutils

I've tried using the suggestions in this thread to no avail: [How to use copyfile when there are spaces in the directory name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500735/how-to-use-copyfile-when-there-are-spaces-in-the-directory-name). To be clear, the directory I'm using is already in double-quotes, and I've tried escaping the spaces, but still get the same error. This is the error message I get:

```
    Error: Failed to open PDF file:
    C:/Documents
    Error: Failed to open PDF file:
    and
    Error: Failed to open PDF file:
    Settings/cpengelly/My
    Error: Failed to open PDF file:
    Documents/Dropbox/theproject/tmp/working/main
    Error: Failed to open PDF file:
    pdf.pdf
    Errors encountered.  No output created.
    Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Maybe some source or something. Did you try escaping the space?

Comment: Yes, tried that and still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to put your directory name in double quotes. example -

```
FileUtils.cp("C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla\\dbghelp.dll","c:\\temp")
```

Comment: I should have clarified that the directory name is already in double-quotes, sorry!

Comment: well in your example absolute file name is not double quoted. Instead of `pdf_path = "#{working_path}\/#{pdf_name}"` you should use `pdf_path = "\"#{working_path}/#{pdf_name}\""`

Comment: Hmmm, tried that and now get this in addition to the previous error: http://pastebin.com/tKdjbX6X  I'm thinking there must be an issue somewhere else in my code at this point.